# Silverlight set browser URL

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight app that i want to set the url of the browser depending what is going on in my app.

Say the app was hosted on at "http://blablabla.co.uk/product.aspx" and navigate to a product the url would change "http://blablabla.co.uk/product.aspx#product=55"

Can this be achieved though silverlight or javascript?

Thanks

Comment: You cant do this as of silverlight .net 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the browser's URL without redirection.
However, you can use anchors "#" and parse them accordingly in your Silverlight code.

For example, "http://blablabla.co.uk/product.aspx#product=55".

Comment: Partly wrong, HTML5 history API does allow for changing the URL without redirection. But only Chrome and FX4 do support it at this time.

Comment: Thumbs up for the information. But I don't think it is a valid choice right now to go with HTML 5.

Comment: its real only to read the query string in silveright, to you think you can set it with reflection?